# Update User ACF information

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, elementor, usermetadata

I have applied a code to create a new user using an elementor pro form, this included a variety of meta data achieved through using ACF fields. However, I am now trying to allow users update these ACF fields from the front end using the same elementor forms. The code I have created (I'm a noob please don't hurt me) doesn't seem to work as I simply recieve form errors and my meta data does not update.

```js
<?php

add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');

    
    //Check that the form is the "Update" if not - stop and return;
    if ('Update' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    
$current_user = wp_get_current_user($user_id); 
        $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();

    // Assign Additional added field value in the created user profile
    $company     =$form_data["Company Name"];
    $yoe         =$form_data["Year Of Establishment"];
    $country     =$form_data["Country"];
    $phone       =$form_data["Phone Number"];
    $website     =$form_data["Website"];
    $cat1        =$form_data["Categories 1"];
    $cat2        =$form_data["Categories 2"];
    $other       =$form_data["OtherCategories"];
    $bus1        =$form_data["Business Type 1"];
    $bus2        =$form_data["Business Type 2"];
    $import      =$form_data["Import Countries"];
    $export      =$form_data["Export Countries"];
    $dischannel  =$form_data["Distribution Channel"];
    $date        =$form_data["Admin Date"];
    $source      =$form_data["Admin Source"];
    $countrycode =$form_data["Country Code"];
    $title       =$form_data["Title"];

    update_user_meta($user, 'company_name', $company);
    update_user_meta($user, 'year_of_establishment', $yoe);
    update_user_meta($user, 'country', $country);
    update_user_meta($user, 'phone_number', $phone);
    update_user_meta($user, 'website', $website);
    update_user_meta($user, 'categories_1', $cat1);
    update_user_meta($user, 'categories_2', $cat2);
    update_user_meta($user, 'othercategories', $other);
    update_user_meta($user, 'business_type_1', $bus1);
    update_user_meta($user, 'business_type_2', $bus2);
    update_user_meta($user, 'import_countries', $import);
    update_user_meta($user, 'export_countries', $export);
    update_user_meta($user, 'distribution_channel', $dischannel);
    update_user_meta($user, 'admin_date', $date);
    update_user_meta($user, 'admin_source', $source);
    update_user_meta($user, 'country_code', $countrycode);
    update_user_meta($user, 'title', $title);
    
    });
```